# Cannot save excel 2016 document located on server after resuming from hibernation

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel-2016, hibernate, read-only

**Problem description**:

1. I have an Excel 2016 spreadsheet open and saved on my file server.
2. I hibernate my Windows 10 leaving the spreadsheet open.
3. I Turn on my Windows 10.
4. I edit my spreadsheet.
5. I try to save my spreadsheet (to the same file) and get the error message:

```
    We can't save 'my-file' because the file is read-only.
    To keep your changes, you'll need to save the workbook with a new name or in a different 
location.
```

The file exists on the server (its the only file in that specific folder) and no one is accessing the file. If I rename the file on the server to a new name and try to save the spreadsheet using the original name, I still get the above message. The title bar on the spreadsheet doesn't say *read-only* and I cannot seem to find any indications to the document being *read-only*.

What can I do to normally save my spreadsheet without creating a new filename, delete the old and rename the new back to the old?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel, please try the following steps, go to File > Options > Save > Under "Offline editing options for document management server files", tick the box "The server drafts location on this computer" instead of "The Office Document Cache" > OK.

Then type "services.msc" in Windows search box > Locate "Offline Files" and right click, and select "Properties"> Make sure the "Start-up type" is "Manual".